# alfresco api response 404 with curl php

Tags: php, laravel, curl, alfresco

Dears,
i want to upload the file to alfresco with laravel / php. but I get an error response like below.

this is my code:

```
$file = "test.txt";
$login = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$postvars = array(
'filename' => $file,
'filedata' => '@'. realpath($file),
'siteid'    => 'IT',
'containerid'   => 'documentLibrary', 
'uploaddirectory' =>'/',
'description' => 'File example',
'contenttype' => 'cm:content',
'overwrite' => 'true',
);
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($login.":".$password) // <---
);

$params_string = '';
foreach($postvars as $key=>$value) { $params_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($params_string, '&');

$curl_request = curl_init();
$url = "http://xxxxxx.com/alfresco/service/api/upload";
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl_request);    

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

his error like this:

```
{ "status" : { "code" : 404, "name" : "Not Found", "description" : "Requested resource is not available." }, "message" : " No disk space available", "exception" : "", "callstack" : [ ], "server" : "Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8,022", "time" : "Jul 19, 2018 3:59:46 PM" }
```

I hope someone can help. thank you.

Comment: Does service at http://xxxxxx.com/alfresco/service/api/upload work OK? because returned message is "No disk space available"

Comment: what service? because i try in postman google chrome is ok. please get the information.

Comment: [SOLVED] 
I use CurlFIle for get the file

Comment: It is worth to write an answer by yourself how exactly you solved your issue and mark it as answered.